# Angular how to fix TypeError: getUnfinishedItemsNumber is not a function?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular project, and I am currently trying to show some data on the screen with the angular double brackets `{{like.this}}`. I have a list of lists (that is a class made by me), where each item has a list of items. An Item has a boolean 'done'. I want to show the unfinished items of a list as a number on the screen.
So I made a function within the List class that looks like this:

```
  public getUnfinishedItemsNumber(): number {
    let returnValue = 0;
    for (const item of this.items) {
      if (!item.done) {
        returnValue = returnValue + 1;
      }
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
```

I try to call the function with the following html code:

```
    <ul class="list-group list-group-hover">
      <div *ngFor="let l of lists">
        <li (click)="goToList(l.id)" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <b>{{l.name}}</b>
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{l.getUnfinishedItemsNumber()}}</span>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

`{{l.name}}` works, yet when I try to call the function with the double brackets, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.getUnfinishedItemsNumber is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (HomeComponent.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23937)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23312)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23308)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
```

When I hard-code a 5 instead of calling the function, it works. When I do `{{l.id}}` instead of calling the function it works. 
Yet, when I put in a new property in the List class like this: `public test = 5;` And I try to call that property, instead of the function, it doesn't work, but without an error.
All the other properties DO work.
A thing to note is that the properties that do work, are the ones that are filled in by the api call.

I do not understand why the function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means that the function is not binded with the listObjects in lists array. its better to call the function like `{{getUnfinishedItemsNumber(l)}}` & do the logic inside that function.